# Change proxy of IE c# for win 7 64 bit(test using httperbrequest to make sure registry change)

Tags: c#, windows-7, proxy, 32bit-64bit

I have been testing my application on 32 bit and it is working fine but as soon it switches to 64 bit OS then there is a problem

> it changes proxy for one time but
>   never again it keeps and tests same
>   proxy for the rest of the loop

.I came across some posts that shows that there is some difference bit 32 and 64 bit registry and have written a code but it dose not work well on 64 bit environment

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)] 


[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] 
public static extern bool IsWow64Process([In] IntPtr hProcess, [Out] out bool lpSystemInfo);

public bool Is64Bit()
{
    bool retVal;

    IsWow64Process(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, out retVal);

    return retVal;
} 

Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey registry;
if (Is64Bit())
{
    MessageBox.Show("Oh HO! you are running 64 bit version");
     registry = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Yes it is 32 bit");
     registry = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true);
}

string orignalProxyServer = registry.GetValue("ProxyServer").ToString();
int orignalProxyEnable = int.Parse(registry.GetValue("ProxyEnable").ToString());
int i = 0;

while (i < listBox1.Items.Count)
{

    //Enter new proxies Settings//
    registry.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 1);
    registry.SetValue("ProxyServer", listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
    RefreshInternetExplorerSettings();

    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp");
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
        {
            resopnse = reader.ReadToEnd();
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DoIe));                       

        }
    }
    catch (Exception c)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(c.Message);

    }
    i++;
    Application.DoEvents();
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
}
registry.SetValue("ProxyEnable", orignalProxyEnable);
registry.SetValue("ProxyServer", orignalProxyServer);
RefreshInternetExplorerSettings();
```

Comment: What do you think you're doing? What are you trying to accomplish with that code? Do you really think that WebRequest stops and reads the registry every time you call it?

Comment: may be i am wrong but i hope web request to do so

Comment: What exactly "dose not work well on 64 bit environment"? Could you please describe the problem itself?

Comment: added problem statement please read .Thank you for pointing out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is quite a dependency on the version of Internet Explorer and the registry nodes it's using:

> For Windows **x86-based** computers:
>
> To change the machine-wide connection attempts:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
>
> To change the user-specific connection attempts:
>   **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings**
>
> For Windows **x64-based** computers:
>
> To change the machine-wide connection attempts for Internet Explorer 32-bit:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
>
> To change the user-specific connection attempts for Internet Explorer **32-bit**:
>   **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings**
>
> To change the machine-wide connection attempts for Internet Explorer 64-bit:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
>
> To change the user-specific connection attempts for Internet Explorer **64-bit**:
>   **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings**

Source: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-internet-explorer-cannot-display-the-webpage#ixzz1DPF9FSvK

I would recommend you to try and use the same node for x86 and x64 systems.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to set the proxy only for the HttpWebRequest, you could do

```
req.Proxy = new WebProxy(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
```

instead of changing the registry settings.

Comment: yes you are right but i need to do it that way because i have to check that my registry writing of proxy is working