# Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey for 64 bit OS

Tags: c#, registry

Hi there i am modifying windows registry it works very well on windows XP but dosenot work on win 7 64 bit it only changes once never again.

I posted question and no answer was found and was wondering that if the following statement is the root cause of trouble

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry registry = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
    "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings",
    true);
```

now here i am changing 64 bit registry but using `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey`
it may not work on 64 bit.

any solutions for changing registry on 64 bit machine

Comment: Have you checked the answers to your same [previos question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937784/change-proxy-of-ie-c-for-win-7-64-bittest-using-httperbrequest-to-make-sure-reg)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't write to that part of the registry without admin rights which you don't have with UAC. It works in XP because you presumably run as an admin there.

You may also need to account for [registry redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

check the option of your project. Are targeting AnyCpu, X86 or x64 ?

I bet there is a mismatch here...

Comment: If you are targeting x86 then you don't need Wow6432Node since the registry redirector takes you there.

Comment: He should *not* target x86 since that will write the wrong key.  AnyCPU is required to make this work correctly.